# Xcode project crash in iPhone Simulator without reaching didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator

My app is crashing about 49 % of the time when running in the iOS Simulator. I have tried to reinstall Xcode, but it is not working.

I'm running Xcode 4.6.2. Help? It works great debugging on a "real" iPhone.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 13th of June 2013 a Xcode update has been released via the Appstore which is solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new bug with OSX 10.8.4 and Xcode. It'll crash due to thread race conditions on trying to kill the previous app running. If you don't update to 10.8.4 it's not an issue.

It's annoying, and you'll have to wait ~5 seconds after stopping the current app before re-running.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/823939#823939